# How to read structure information from an input file in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, input, structure

I am trying to store data from an input file into a structure but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Here is the input file.

```
4 2     1 1     3 1

1 1     2 1     3 1

1 1     5 3     1 1
```

The first number in each should be stored as sand and the second should be stored as treasure.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PIRATES
#define MAP_SIZE 3

//structures
struct pirate {
    int dig;
    int carry;
};

struct map {
    int sand;
    int treasure;
};


//functions
int hours_crew ();
void scan_file ();

//main function
int main() {
    FILE * ifp = NULL;
    struct map map[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE];
    int i, j;
    char filename[30];

    printf("You have arrived at Treasure Island!\n");

    while (ifp == NULL) {
        printf("What is the name of your map?\n");
        scanf("%s", &filename);

        ifp = fopen(filename, "r");
    }

    for(i=0; i<MAP_SIZE; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<MAP_SIZE; j++) {
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &map[i][j].sand);
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &map[i][j].treasure);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<MAP_SIZE; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<MAP_SIZE*2; j++) {
            printf("%d", map[i][j].sand);
            printf("%d\n", map[i][j].treasure);
        }
    }


    fclose(ifp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (j=0; j<MAP_SIZE*2; j++) {` in your display loop... that is _wrong_. Is that your issue? (you didn't describe your issue)

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looked so nicely so I decided to take copy it and see what went wrong.

Really good job on the order, just add some commenting and it will be a professional work.

Just please next time read the instructions about [how to write a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and explain more what is the problem.

Any way before going in to the problem with the structure, there is a warning coming up on line 34 which is:

```
scanf("%s", &filename);
```

> format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[30]'

It can be fixed easily if you change it to:

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

Now, as far as I understand, There is no problem with the structure.

If you will just change the printing from:

```
for (j=0; j<MAP_SIZE*2; j++) {
```

to:

```
for (j=0; j<MAP_SIZE; j++) {
```

It will look just great.

GL